# Using LibGDX inside Android Project as Fragment : How do i call libgdx method from android part?

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx, fragment

I am using libGDX inside android project as fragment all with kotlin and its working fine.

What i am trying to do is **call a method of libgdx part of project from android part(MainActivity) of the project.**

So for example if user presses on button which is made by android part,object in game will move.

First of all this is the project structure:

[image]

MainActivity:

```
package com.krytasoft.androidwithlibgdx


import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment  throws unresolved error.without this compiles fine and works but shows type mismatch error.

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
import com.krytasoft.gdxandroid.AndroidGameFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val libgdxGameFragment:AndroidGameFragment = AndroidGameFragment()
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.openFlexBoxTestButton)
        val moveRightButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.moveRightButton)



        //never mind if this supportFragmentManager... shows type mismatch error.Its working. this line puts libgdx into fragment.fragment is similar to component in react.
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, libgdxGameFragment, AndroidGameFragment::class.java.simpleName).commit()

        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, FlexBoxTestActivity::class.java)
               startActivity(intent)

        }
        moveRightButton.setOnClickListener {
            libgdxGameFragment.moveRight()

        }
    }




    override fun exit() {

    }
}
```

Here in MainActivity, notice moveRightButton.Its calling `moveRight()` function from fragment.

AndroidFragment class:

```
package com.krytasoft.gdxandroid

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
import com.krytasoft.mygdxgame.core.MyGdxGame



class AndroidGameFragment : AndroidFragmentApplication() {
     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        return initializeForView(MyGdxGame(), config)
    }

    override fun startActivity(intent: Intent?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    fun moveRight(){
        MyGdxGame().moveRight()


    }
}
```

MyGDX Game:

```
package com.krytasoft.mygdxgame.core

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch

class MyGdxGame : ApplicationAdapter() {
    lateinit var batch: SpriteBatch
    lateinit var img: Texture
    lateinit var sprite:Sprite


    override fun create() {
        batch = SpriteBatch()
        img = Texture("badlogic.jpg")
        sprite = Sprite(img)
        println("create done from libgdx")
    }

    override fun render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        batch.begin()
        batch.draw(sprite, 50f, 50f)
        batch.end()
    }

    override fun dispose() {

        batch.dispose()
        img.dispose()

    }

   fun moveRight(){
      sprite.x +=50f;    // throws lateinit var sprite is uninitialzied error.



    }


}
```

So what i expect is after pressing move right button,eventually call fun moveRight in mylibgdxgame and change position of sprite.

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property sprite has not been initialized
```

eventhough its initialized.But for some reason its not seen.

I uploaded my project to github:
https://github.com/lastpeony/libgdx-in-android-kotlin

Answer (score 2):

Call  `create()` method before using `MyGdxGame` instance. Also use a single instance of `MyGdxGame` across fragment.

```
class AndroidGameFragment : AndroidFragmentApplication() {
     val myGdxGame = MyGdxGame()

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        myGdxGame.create()
        return initializeForView(myGdxGame, config)
    }

    fun moveRight(){
        myGdxGame .moveRight()
    }
}
```

Comment: sprite batch throws error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.getWidth()' on a null object reference  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:108)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:80)
        at com.krytasoft.mygdxgame.core.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.kt:17)
        at com.krytasoft.gdxandroid.AndroidGameFragment.onCreateView(AndroidGameFragment.kt:21)

Comment: @lastpeony4 It is another issue. I believe you need to create a new question for this.

Comment: I dont think it needs a new question.The main problem is communication between android project and libgdx.

Comment: `Gdx.graphics` is `null`. So you have some problems with initialization/configuration of library. I can't help you with this.